# Import a struct from a download link in matlab

Tags: matlab

Hello I'm trying to write a script to get a specific matrix from web(specifically the CollegeMsg from SNAP collection of uci). The problem I'm having is that this matrix(https://sparse.tamu.edu/SNAP/CollegeMsg) is given from a download link (https://sparse.tamu.edu/mat/SNAP/CollegeMsg.mat). Since this script is part of a school project, it's required to get struct and load it into matlab.

My method of doing that is simple to download it and load it :

```
web('https://sparse.tamu.edu/mat/SNAP/CollegeMsg.mat')
pause(5) %This is so it gives me some time to save the file before loading it
load('C:\Users\User\Documents\CollegeMsg.mat')
x = Problem.A
```

This pretty much does the job but I'm searching for a more direct way that doesn't involve downloading the file into my computer. Is there such a way?

Comment: Why does downloading the file bother you?

Comment: I want the script to run in other pcs as well as mine.

Comment: Okay? so why  does downloading the file bother you?

Comment: the load() command works if I know where the file is. If the user has the option to choose where to download it, the directory might not be the same

Comment: Then you can make the path to the file to load relative to the location of the script (given that this is the current working directory in Matlab)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
load(webread('https://sparse.tamu.edu/mat/SNAP/CollegeMsg.mat'))
```

Comment: "Error using load.Must be a string scalar or character vector.". That's the error I'm getting, and besides webread() doesn't work well with download links